# cheerio js get elements in pair

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I'm trying to get pair of elements
for example I have this text

```
<div id="special">
 <p>not to take</p>
 <p> no to take 2</p>
 <h3> h3 not take<h3>
<h2>
title1
</h2>
<p>
description1
</p>

<h2>
title2
</h2>
<p>
description2
</p>

<h2>
title3
</h2>
<p>
description4
</p>
</div>
```

so I want to get in pairs the h2 and p to get array of
[{h2:title1,p:description1},{h2:title2,p:description3}]
and I don't want to take the p (up the h2 - p "not to take"), just h2 and p 
what I tried to do is

```
  let title2 = $('#special').find('h2').each((index,element)=>{
                let title = $(element).text()
                let p = $(element).find('p')
                console.log('title:',title)
                console.log('p:',p)

            })
```

but it not find the p element

Comment: Pay attention that while you are looking for the div with the id of special, you are using find on the h2 elements and your paragraph tags are not part of it. That is why the paragraph tags are not being found. Why not use find for all the paragraph elements inside the special div(similar to what you did for h2)?

Comment: yes you right,p is not child of h2.. to your question, because I have more p elements that I don't want them, I will edit my example and let you see

Comment: If this html is generated by you, why not wrap the h2 and p elements inside of divs and just iterate over those? Or if you don't want to do that, add a class to the p elements you want to take.

Comment: it's not by me, i make request to any api

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently finding the `p` element inside the element because `.find()` checks for children but in your case, `<p>` tag is the sibling instead. For your case, you have to use `.next()` method instead if you're sure that very next sibling is `<p>` tag having description. Check below code:

```
let title2 = $('#special').find('h2').each((index, element)=>{
                let title = $(element).text()
                let p = $(element).next()
                console.log('title:',title)
                console.log('p:',p)

            })
```

Comment: if I want to get all elements until next h2, for example I have h2,p,p,ul and then h2. how to do it?

Comment: @AdirZoari  Add a while loop and keep checking `next` element and if next element is h2, break the loop. It's more like a logical problem now.

Comment: while($(element).next()){
                            console.log('desc',$(element).next().text())
                        }   but it show me the same text always